# How to access parent object in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am creating a Custom UITableViewCell with a UITextfield in it, I would like to know how to access the the custom UItableViewCell from the UITextField delegate didend?

I am trying this

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    CustomFinishingCell *updateCell = (CustomFinishingCell *)textField.superview;
```

but that's not returning a UITableViewCell, I think it's returning the UItableScrollView or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `textField`'s superview will actually be the cell's `contentView`. You could probably get the cell by doing:

```
CustomFinishingCell *updateCell = (CustomFinishingCell *)textField.superview.superview;
```

That's a little clunky though.

I also wouldn't recommend using tags as that's even more clunky.

What I would do, is create a subclass of `UITextField` with a property for your `CustomFinishingCell` and set that when creating the cell (where you add the `UITextField`). That will ensure everything keeps working, even if the user resorts the cells, adds/removes cells etc, and will work well with cell reuse.

**Update:**

In a lot of cases, it will be better to actually use @TimReddy's answer and set the `delegate` of the `UITextField` to the `CustomFinishingCell` and move the `- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField` etc code to that subclass. That will save you having to create another subclass for `UITextField`.

Comment: It's not clunky. The link between the objects only needs to be set once and won't ever break. Its going to give you faster performance than doing calculations on point locations and looking up the row every time. @TimReddy's answer of setting the delegate of the `UITextField` is a probably a better answer in most cases, since it avoids another subclass.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have your custom `UITableViewCell` be that `UITextView's` delegate.  That way you know for certain when the delegate fires it is that `UITableViewCell's` text view.

You may need to so some cleanup work before the UITableViewCell gets recycled tho.

Answer (score 0):

You could give each cell view a `tag`, then call UIView's `viewWithTag` to get the view with the specified tag.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html

Comment: this seems like a bit of a hack.. I am reading though apple docs but struggling to find something that will work.. surly there is a way to access the elements parent object....

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it:

```
 NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:[textField convertPoint:textField.frame.origin toView:self.tableView]];
 UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

I prefer this approach because it doesn't rely on tags or maintaining a reference to the container view from the UITextField, or traversing the view hierarchy.  All those approaches are brittle for one reason or another.

- Tags approach: You need to set the tag in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and if you have multiple sections, you need to encode the section.
- Adding a property to UITextField:  This either requires a UITextField category and associated objects, or subclassing UITextField.  Both work, but are overkill.
- Traversing the view hierarchy is brittle because it depends on implementation details that could change at any time.

Comment: This solution is indeed cleaner, but I wonder if the OP is ok if `cellForRowAtIndexPath` returns nil.  From the docs: `Return Value
An object representing a cell of the table or nil if the cell is not visible or indexPath is out of range.`